# Can we Pass multiple variables through POST and GET tags in PHP

Tags: php

I ran two SQL queries in a page and want to pass those variable to anotherpage.. 
i know that i can pass one variable attached it to the anchor link but can we do that for two variables with single link?

The usual passing single variable:

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo $row['variable1'];?>" ><li style="font-size:14px;"><strong>LINK</strong></li></a>
```

On the other page(#2) we can call the passed variable using `$id = $_GET["id"];` method..

Now as per my situation, is it possible for two variables:

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo $row['variable1'];?> ?id2=<?php echo $row2['variable2'];?>" ><li style="font-size:14px;"><strong>LINK</strong></li></a>
```

If it is possible, did i done anything wrong in the above code...
Any Help is Appreciated..

Comment: You only use 1 `?`. You use `&` to add additional url parameters -> `page2.php?id=...&id2=...&id3=...`

Comment: Thanks man.. it worked like charm.. Answer the comment..

Comment: Be sure to look up [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) and [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use the Ampersand char to add more variables "&"

try do some more nice code and cleaning some non acceptable chars in your case with the $_GET method.

```
<?php
function cleanvar($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    $var_1 = cleanvar($row['variable1']);
    $var_2 = cleanvar($row['variable2']);

?>

<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo $var_1;?>&id2=<?php echo $var_2;?>"><li style="font-size:14px;"><strong>LINK</strong></li></a>
```

Maybe you can use some referer param like " &referer=mypage1.php" and create some condition like

```
if($_GET['referer'] == 'mypage1.php'){ //save or do something }else{ //nothing or do somthing}
```

hoping that helps you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read a bit on the HTTP GET method. Here is a [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) on what you are doing
However for brevity passing multiple arguments requires an **&**, hence your query might look something like this:

```
<a href="page2.php?id=<?php echo $row['variable1'] . "&key=" . $row['variable2']; ?>"></a>
```

Comment: John, why the double quotations and concat on the key?

Comment: All your basically doing is injecting values into the HTML. The <?php ?> code is basically telling php to interpret the code and spit out the values of variables into the anchor tag. In other words the final string will look something like this: page2.php?id=27&name=bob